# About two moving points on Euclidean plane (absolute space)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, reference-frames, vectors

Two points are moving on Euclidean plane (absolute space) smoothly and in every instance velocity vector of each of them is in the direction of the position of the other one.

Is it true that they are both on a fixed line?

Comment: *"in the direction of the position of the other one"* can mean two things: in the direction of the position *vector* of the other point, or in the direction of the *relative* position ($\vec{r_2}-\vec{r_1}$) between the two points. Even more importantly, when asking for homework help you should show what you tried, otherwise this will likely be closed...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If the objects have position vectors $\vec r_1$ and $\vec r_2$ then the position vector of object $2$ relative to object $1$ is $\vec r_{12} = \vec r_2 - \vec r_1$. Consider the rate of change of $\vec r_{12}$.